# Parser Error & Server Error in '/' Application :(

Tags: asp.net, ajax, parsing

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Source Error:

'Line 1:  `<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="news.aspx.vb" Inherits="news" %>`
Line 2:
Line 3:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
Line 4:      TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

'
Line 5:

Source File: /news/news.aspx    Line: 3

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.

'WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].'

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

can any body tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy the needed files (.dll) of the ajax control toolkit in the /bin subfolder?

If this is an ASP.NET 2.0 application you also have to install the Ajax 1.0 extensions first in order to get it to work. Also you have to make sure that you use the correct ajax control toolkit which maps to the exact .NET framework version under which your application's running. You can't just plug in the latest toolkit version as you wish.

Comment: well , i added the (.dll) files to the bin subfolder.
and i am using .net 3.5 and ajax 3.5

do i need any thing else?
you can check this:
http://www.ittejahatcenter.com/news/news.aspx

Comment: i solved this by adding the Ajax .dll to my website/web/cgi-bin folder

and it's working now.


thank you so much mr.8 for your help.